# IntelliJ svn not a working copy for .idea and .iml outside project

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I have set up my IntelliJ project so that .iml files and the .idea directory are located **outside** the project. The project itself is under Subversion source control. The .idea and .iml files are not.

The SVN integration is not working: in the project file tree, a changed file may appear blue or black. If I try to update the project, nothing happens.

I can only suspect the following errors in the view "Subversion working copy information" cause IJ to be confused:

```
C:\Project\intellij
URL: svn: E204899: E155007: C:\Project\intellij is not a working copy
Format: unknown        Change
Depth: unknown

C:\Project\intellij\.idea
URL: svn: E204899: E155007: C:\Project\intellij is not a working copy
Format: unknown
Depth: unknown        Change
```

Of course these directories are no working copies; I have purposefully set up the project to keep .idea and *.iml out of it.

How can I get rid of this error and be able to use SVN in IJ?

(Keeping .idea and .iml files in the project and excluding them from the project is not the desired solution: about 40 .iml and IJ is only tolerated on this project. I believe this should work as is.)

IntelliJ 13.1.6.

```
svn --version
svn, version 1.7.9-SilkSvn-1.7.9-X64(SilkSvn/1.7.9) X64
```

*EDIT* Current workaround: I have recreated the project, leaving .idea and *.iml together with the project files under version control. In `%appdata%\Subversion\config`, I've set `ignore-global` to `.idea *.iml`, so now svn simply ignores them. But yet...